# Processing: Can you draw outside of the Processing Class?

Tags: java, function, class, processing, jetbrains-ide

I am trying to organize code to where I can draw outside of the main processing class, However, I am getting a `NullPointerExeption` whenever I attempt to do so.

```
public class Processing extends PApplet {

    PApplet p = new PApplet();
    Screen homeScreen = new Screen(new Vector2(0, 0), p);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PApplet.runSketch(new String[]{"Processing"},
                new Processing());


    }

    public void settings() {
// Setup
        size(500, 500);

        TextBox t = new TextBox(new Vector2(0, 0), new Vector2(300, 300), new PApplet());
        homeScreen.addContent(t);
    }
}
```

I am calling the `display()` method in the `TextBox` Class shown below.

```
public void display() {

        // Text Box Body
        p.pushMatrix();
        p.fill(240);
        p.rect(pos.getPos()[0], pos.getPos()[1], dimensions.getPos()[0], dimensions.getPos()[1]);

    }
```

`p` is a `PApplet` Object passed through the constructor. The Exeption is shown below.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at processing.core.PApplet.pushMatrix(PApplet.java:13149)
    at TextBox.display(Processing.java:154)
    at Screen.display(Processing.java:83)
    at Processing.draw(Processing.java:29)
    at processing.core.PApplet.handleDraw(PApplet.java:2426)
    at processing.awt.PSurfaceAWT$12.callDraw(PSurfaceAWT.java:1557)
    at processing.core.PSurfaceNone$AnimationThread.run(PSurfaceNone.java:316)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

If I comment out `pushMatrix()` the same error occurs, just pointing to the `fill()` function.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Caution: You are creating multiple instances of `PApplet`, this will make your code confusing, and you will encounter errors. The `Processing` class already extends `PApplet`, so delete this line  `PApplet p = new PApplet();` and replace it with `Processing p = this;` or instead of of `new Screen(new Vector2(0, 0), p);` you can use the `this` keyword like so `new Screen(new Vector2(0, 0), this);`

Answer (score 0):

Caution: You are creating multiple instances of `PApplet`, this will make your code confusing, and you will encounter errors. The `Processing` class already extends `PApplet`, so delete this line `PApplet p = new PApplet();` and replace it with `Processing p = this;` or instead of `new Screen(new Vector2(0, 0), p);` you can use the `this` keyword like so: `new Screen(new Vector2(0, 0), this);` - Thanks @sorifiend